# How to deploy and host ASP.NET MVC web application on windows server 2022 and ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, hosting, ubuntu-22.04, windows-server-2022

I developed web application using ASP.NET framework 4.7.2 in Visual Studio 2022.
I used MSSQL database.
I should deploy it on the following servers.
OS: windows server 2022 (cloudzy.com), ubuntu 22.04 (hostinger.com)

I've read some blogs and articles on how to deploy and host this, but it doesn't help much.
I think it's because I'm new to ASP.NET development using C#.

How to do?
I need step-by-step guide.